# Chrome Locking up Session

Tags: gnome, google-chrome, flash, chromium

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed, running Gnome 3, and yesterday I installed Pepper Flash. Ever since Chrome has been locking up on different webpages. At first it was strictly Youtube but now it seems to be others sites also. Anything with any type of flash or heavy scripting.

I would be comfortable with Chromium crashing and simply reloading it. But when it crashes, it locks up my whole session and even after entering the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>), and killing all the Chromium processes it still shows a frozen screen with Chromium up. I can see my mouse pointer move up on the top menu bar, but the Gnome interface is unresponsive as well.

I am a total newbie to troubleshooting Linux. What else can I do to get my session back without rebooting my box?

Also where can I check the logs to see if Pepper Flash is my issue?

Comment: Chrome or chromium? Its confusing

Comment: @SeanLeftBelow I'm not sure that Pepper flash causes the problem.<br>
I have also google crhome crash on Ubuntu 12.04 independently of the webpages that is opened.<br>
I then open chrome from the terminal with **google-chrome --disable-gpu** command.<br> It seems to avoid crashes.
But i think that it's very ennoying to open it every time like that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling pepper flash in chromium plugins `chrome://plugins/`. If the problem persists it's not pepper. Though I don't think pepper can cause such a desktop issue.

You may also try using google-chrome and see if things change. Its default flash plugin might work.

Linux troubleshooting starts with `/var/log/syslog` - the log file for your desktop. Check it to figure out what happened.

Comment: All is well, but how do I get my session back without rebooting the box?

Comment: @SeanLeftBelow Try `export DISPLAY=:0` and then `sudo service gdm restart`.

Comment: @Seth, I did actually just that. I found someone to help in the #gnome IRC and they had me run;<br/>
  
strings /proc/$(pidof gnome-session)/environ | grep DBUS  
strings /proc/$(pidof gnome-session)/environ | grep DISPLAY  
  
which didn't really fix my issue until I did an export on their outputs. Then a gnome-shell --restart which left me with a giant black screen. After some further discussion we realized the issue might be with my video card drivers. I replaced my video card and I will continue to test to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: @SeanLeftBelow sorry, was unavailable. When you are completely locked out (the machine is not responding to changing ttys or any other method), you may try sshing from another machine and restart your session. This will save you a reboot.
Btw, was the issue resolved?

Comment: @Sudhanshu, I was able to SSH in and try some commands to get the session rebooted and had no luck.

Comment: @Sudhanshu the problem seems to be resolved with a new videocard. Which would also explain other previous issues I was having.